# Linux - reasons for preemption

Tags: linux-kernel, context-switch, preemption

I want to update the kernel to do some more stuff when switching between tasks and for that i need to find the reason for each switch.

First, i can't find the function where schedule() is called when there is a **higher priority task than the current one** and they need to be switched, where does it happen?

Second, is there any reason for a task **to yield the CPU rather than exiting or going to wait** for something? is there a yield function or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check this prio_changed_fair (similar you can refer other scheduling class)
2. Task will not yield if it is in infinite loop but kernel can schedule another task based on time-slice. Yes linux has yield function.

Comment: Thanks! I found the yield function, i couldn't find the prio_changed_fair function, do you know in wich file it appears? thankss

Comment: Which kernel version are you using?. In latest kernel it is in kernel/sched/fair.c

Comment: I'm using a super old one, 2.4.18-14

Comment: That one too old. Check kernel/sched.c (schedule + line number 608)

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-old+v2.4.18/kernel/sched.c#L608

And " goodness" function the same file
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-old+v2.4.18/kernel/sched.c#L144